# I have 2-3 numbers in a single string having space between them how to add those all the numbers in a new column?

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have a column ML_Latest which contains values as following  :

ML_Latest

1st row)95  250 95

2nd row)95  500

3rd row)250 500

I want to make a new column which contains the addition of these numbers for example:

```
440

595

750
```

How can I do it in R?

Comment: Look into the `rowSums()` function.

Comment: Please make your example reproducible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

Using `rowSums`:

Your dataset:

```
df=read.table(text="95 250 95
          95 500 NA
          250 500 NA",header=FALSE)

df$sum=rowSums(df,na.rm = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
   V1  V2 V3 sum
1  95 250 95 440
2  95 500 NA 595
3 250 500 NA 750
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response but i have Column called Latest under that column i have in 1st row 95 250 95 in 2nd row i have 95 500 and in 3rd row i have 250 500 so it means 95 500 95 is in 1 cell

Comment: @ShantamMalgaonkar: I have added sample dataset for you. Please let me know your views!

Comment: @ Saurabh Chauhan giving me this error-Error in rowSums(df$ML_clean_NEW, na.rm = TRUE) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Comment: @ShantamMalgaonkar: Could you please share your data using `dput`?

Comment: my column is a character column